# TwitterException {statusCode=403, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null}

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have recently noticed that I keep getting a 403 error while doing twitter search. My application was working until couple of days back when i noticed the error.

I checked with Twitter & they say my IP is not blocked, I am also within the rate limit = about 60 search requests/per hour.

Here's how i was initializing the Twitter object -

```
private static Twitter TWITTER_CLIENT = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
```

After i noticed the error, i tried the following & still no success -

```
private static Twitter TWITTER_CLIENT = new TwitterFactory().getInstance("user", "password");
```

Here's how i am searching -

```
TWITTER_CLIENT.search(new Query("#keyword1 OR #keyword2"));
```

I tried this URL (curl http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=ipad) from my server & it works alright.

Following is the exception. I am on java6 + Twitter4j v2.1.2. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
TwitterException{statusCode=403, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:301)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:68)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:82)
    at twitter4j.Twitter.search(Twitter.java:193)
```

Comment: this is a twitter API bug - http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1863

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason is basic auth shutdown by Twitter (aka OAuthcalypse):

[Basic Auth Shutdown](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_auth_shutdown)

You need to switch to using [OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_to_oauth).

Comment: links have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i got the same error while executing similar code.
To fix it, please go to

1. https://apps.twitter.com/app/your_app_id
2. Click on Keys and access token
3. In Access Level, click modify app permission and choose the 3rd option: Read, Write and Access direct messages
4. Click on update. ( Note: you might have to add your mobile no and verify with otp to get this access if you dont have your no added in twitter)
5. Regenerate both Consumer key & secretand Access token & secret using the clickable button
6. Us e the new keys in your program

And you are done! Your program will start working.